# Why are they adding 1 to the RandomInt Integer here?

Tags: java

I'm studying code from Horstmann's java book:

```
Integer key = new Random().nextInt(elements.length) + 1;
```

What puzzles me is the +1 part , is there any reason for this, or just for more "randomness"? Thanks alot!

Comment: To get the range between 1...length and not 0....length-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nextInt()` returns a number more than or equal to zero and less than its parameter.

`+ 1` shifts that range.

Answer (score 3):

I think the `+1` is to shift the domain of random integers, from

> [0,elements.length-1]

to

> [1, elements.length]

Horstmann simply wants a random integer from 1 to elements.length for his key.

Answer (score 2):

> is there any reason for this, or just for more "randomness"?

No this does not add "randomness", `1` is clearly not random, this is to shift the range from `[0,elements.length-1]` to `[1,elements.length]`.